# Oracle connect by clause

Tags: sql, oracle, connect-by

I have below data available in a table called say EXPENSE :

```
Account DEPT EXPENSE_AMT
------------------------
1001 DEPT_A 50000
1002 DEPT_B 100000
1003 DEPT_C 10000000
1004 DEPT_D 500000
1005 DEPT_E 1000
```

These departments are controlled by PARENT department. Table name say PARENT_CHILD

```
CHILD_DEPT PARENT_DEPT
----------------------
DEPT_A DEPT_E
DEPT_B DEPT_E
DEPT_C DEPT_F
DEPT_D DEPT_F
DEPT_E DEPT_G
DEPT_F DEPT_G
```

I need a Oracle SQL query using Oracle connect by clause which produces output like below :

```
CHILD_DEPT PARENT_DEPT DIRECT_FLAG TOTAL_EXPENSE
------------------------------------------------
DEPT_A DEPT_E Y 50000
DEPT_B DEPT_E Y 100000
DEPT_E DEPT_G N 150000
DEPT_C DEPT_F Y 10000000
DEPT_D DEPT_F Y 500000
DEPT_F DEPT_G N 10500000
DEPT_E DEPT_G Y 1000
```

No row required for the top parent DEPT_G(i.e no need to put DEPT_G in CHILD_DEPT column)

Comment: Why you want this in CONNECT BY ?

Comment: Any solution is fine. Connect by is not required.

Answer (score 0):

In your examples, you didn't specify where is the DIRECT_FLAG column, as it's important and must be in GROUP BY clause.

I assumed that the column is located in EXPENSE table.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
    CHILD_DEPT, PARENT_DEPT, DIRECT_FLAG, sum(EXPENSE_AMT) TOTAL_EXPENSE
FROM 
    PARENT_CHILD, EXPENSE
WHERE
    DEPT = CHILD_DEPT
GROUP BY CHILD_DEPT, PARENT_DEPT, DIRECT_FLAG;
```

**Example**

```
WITH 
    EXPENSE AS (
        select 1001 as Account, 'DEPT_A' as DEPT ,50000 as EXPENSE_AMT, 'Y' DIRECT_FLAG  from dual
        union all select 1002 ,'DEPT_B',100000, 'Y'  from dual
        union all select 1003 ,'DEPT_C',10000000, 'Y'  from dual
        union all select 1004 ,'DEPT_D',500000, 'Y'  from dual
        union all select 1005 ,'DEPT_E',1000, 'Y'  from dual
        union all select 1005 ,'DEPT_E',50000 , 'N' from dual
        union all select 1005 ,'DEPT_E',50000, 'N'  from dual
        union all select 1005 ,'DEPT_E',50000, 'N'  from dual
        union all select 1033 ,'DEPT_F',10000000, 'N' from dual
        union all select 1033 ,'DEPT_F',500000, 'N'  from dual),
    PARENT_CHILD AS (
        select 'DEPT_A' as CHILD_DEPT,'DEPT_E' as PARENT_DEPT from dual
        union all select 'DEPT_B','DEPT_E'  from dual
        union all select 'DEPT_C','DEPT_F'  from dual
        union all select 'DEPT_D','DEPT_F'  from dual
        union all select 'DEPT_E','DEPT_G'  from dual
        union all select 'DEPT_F','DEPT_G'  from dual
    )
SELECT 
    CHILD_DEPT, PARENT_DEPT, DIRECT_FLAG, sum(EXPENSE_AMT) TOTAL_EXPENSE
FROM 
    PARENT_CHILD, EXPENSE
WHERE
    DEPT = CHILD_DEPT
GROUP BY CHILD_DEPT, PARENT_DEPT, DIRECT_FLAG;
```